# my textarea text is clearing after button submits it

Tags: javascript, html, forms, button, submit

my code below deletes the text from my textarea that is inserted by a user after clicking the submit button but what i want is i want the text to be in my textarea after submit.

```
  <form action="/search" name="myform" id="formid" method="post"   >
                      <div class="input-group" >
            <!--          
        
                          <textarea  name="input" id="textArea" />
        
                          
        
        
                            <button type="submit" onclick="return fill()" >Search</button>
                          </button>
        
                      </div>
        
                    </form>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
                    function fill()
                    {
        
                     var x = document.getElementById('textArea').value;
                     document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML=x;
        
        
        
                    }
                </script>
```

Comment: Form element is a link, it loads the page addressed in `action` attribute (or what ever that page returns from the server). If you want to post the data and stay on the current page, you need to use AJAX to send the data.

Comment: Change type to button instead of submit

Comment: @KrishnaReddyBandi Bad idea, OP wants to submit the form.

Answer (score 0):

Simply try to add onSubmit="return false;" at the form tag

```
<form action="/search" onSubmit="return false;" name="myform" id="formid" method="post"   >
```

Comment: i have tried it but it hold the text but it is not submiting the text

Comment: You need to submit it to the /search page?

Comment: when i add " onsubmit= return false;" to my form the buttons are not submiting even i use either "type ='button ' or type='submit'

Comment: function fill(){
     var inputtext= document.getElementById("input");
     localStorage.setItem("input", inputtext.value);
    }

Comment: thanks and i solved it using the above code

Comment: update your question with your solution, for someone else